# How to extract required data?

Tags: c#, regex

The serial data I receive is like this

```
AT+CMGR=3

+CMGR: "REC READ","919742400000",,"2014/01/17 22:52:44+22"  
G LED ON

OK
```

Actually it will be like this

```
AT+CMGR=3\r\n\r\n+CMGR: "REC READ","919742400000",,"2014/01/17 22:52:44+22"\r\nG LED ON\r\n\r\n\r\nOK\r\n
```

I need to extract

3           (Message Index can have any integer value)

REC READ        (Msg Status)

919742400000        (Originating Number)

2014/01/17 22:52:44+22  (Date Time Stamp)

G LED ON        (Actual Message SMS)

The VC#.Net code that I have written is

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\+CMGR: (\d+),""(.+)"",""(.+)"",(.*),""(.+)""\r\n(.+)\r\n");
Match m = r.Match(mySMS); //mySMS is a string and contains the above mentioned data


int Index = int.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value);   //(3 in above example)
string Status = m.Groups[2].Value;      //(REC READ)
string Sender = m.Groups[3].Value;      //(919742400000)
string Sent = m.Groups[4].Value;        //2014/01/17 22:52:44+22
string Message = m.Groups[5].Value;     //G LED ON
```

Another thing is The actual message (SMS) can contain double quoted strings like

"G "LED" ON" and I might also be able to extract

G "LED" ON

The above VC# code is not working.

How can I use RegEx or any other method to extract the required datas?

Answer (score 3):

I would say your main structure is line-based, ie you either use ReadLine() oryou split the string:

```
string[] lines = mySMS.Split(new string[] {"\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Now `lines[2]` constians your main data, comma-separated. `lines[3]` is your `G "LED" ON`.

To parse lines[2]:

```
string[] parts = lines[2].Split(',');
string OriginatingNumber = parts[1];
string DateTimeStamp = parts[3];
```

`parts[0]` will hold `+CMGR: "REC READ"`, use another Split() or break on the `:` some other way.

Comment: `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmpty` would take care of the "empty" split on the `\r\n\r\n`, resulting in a 3 rather than a 4 element array.

Comment: @Tim - yes, but those empties might be there for a reason. I'd rather stay close to the format as given.

Comment: I need only text between double quotes in the +CMGR line and I need text with double quotes if any in the actual message to be extracted. If I separate with (,) then I will get "REC READ", "919742400000", "2014/01/17 22:52:44+22" but I need REC READ, 919742400000, 2014/01/17 22:52:44+22 without double quotes and Actual message as G LED ON if it was G LED ON and as G "LED" ON if it were G "LED" ON. I don't need ("), ( ), (,) from +CMGR line.

Comment: `s = s.Replace("\"", "");`